# Импортировать из папки выше?

Tags: python, pycharm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу импортировать класс Articles models из sport_articles в scrape.py в папке comms.
Вызываю так sport_articles.models import Articles, но ничего не выходит.
Появляется исключение Unresolved reference 'sport_articles'

Comment: Что значит "ничего не выходит"? Есть какое-то исключение? Если есть, приведите его, пожалуйста, в вопрос, нажав кнопку [edit]

Comment: Все, я исправил

Answer (score 0):

добавил в comms файл `__init__.py` и импортировал содержимое из файла models.py таким способом

```
import os
import sys

sys.path.insert(1, os.path.join(sys.path[0], '..'))
from  .models import Articles
```

Comment: а что мешало `from ..models import Articles` ? без плясок с бубном?

Comment: Потому что орлы в клетке не сидят

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте `init.py` в `TopProject/articles`

```
import sport_articles
```

И теперь можно использовать

```py
from TopProject.articles import sport_articles
```